# How to map a C function to Java Native Method using JavaCpp

Tags: java, c

In JavaCpp github wiki, I notice that it have Tutorial about access C++ class. But There is not any information about how to access C Library function in java using JavaCpp.

I have a  C Library, in the library there are some C function, and i want to use JavaCpp Annotation to create a java Class and use java native method to access those C function.

I don't know how to do it. 
Is there someone can give me a simple example about how to use JavaCpp to create a Java Class to access C function.
Attention  that not C++ Library. 
Thank you Very Much.

Comment: It's an interface strictly designed for Java <-> CPP, why do you think it has plain C support if it doesn't say that in the Github page?